# R: Checking if mutliple elements of a vector appear in vector of strings

Tags: r, list, vector, grepl

I'm trying to create a function that checks if all elements of a vector appear in a vector of strings. The test code is presented below:

```
test_values = c("Alice", "Bob")
test_list = c("Alice,Chris,Mark", "Alice,Bob,Chris", "Alice,Mark,Zach", "Alice,Bob,Mark", "Mark,Bob,Zach", "Alice,Chris,Bob", "Mark,Chris,Zach")
```

I would like the output for this to be `FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE`.

I first thought I'd be able to switch the `|` to `&` in the command `grepl(paste(test_values, collapse='|'), test_list)` to get when Alice and Bob are **both** in the string instead of when either of them appear, but I was unable to get the correct answer.

I also would rather not use the command: `grepl(test_values[1], test_list) & grepl(test_values[2], test_list)` because the `test_values` vector will change dynamically (varying from length 0 to 3), so I'm looking for something to take that into account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `grepl`

```
Reduce(`&`, lapply(test_values, grepl, test_list))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```